# Use conditions in GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have the following database:

```
+-------+-------------+---------+
| id    | Name        | Quantity| 
+-------+-------------+---------+
| 1     | Anna        | 0       | 
| 2     | John        | 5       |
| 3     | Anna        | 3       |
+-------+-------------+------+
```

I am using this query:

```sql
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT quatity SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```

As results I got this:

> **Anna**: 0, 3
>   **John**: 5

However I want something like this:

> **Anna**: 3 (I don't want to show ***quantity = 0***)
>   **John**: 5

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```sql
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    CASE
    WHEN quantity > 0 THEN name
    else null
    END
  ORDER BY name ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
```

Comment: `name` may need to be back-ticked, it is a MySQL keyword. `Quantity` != `quatity` Are there just a bunch of typos here?

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause with negation operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone suggested this but I'll put it in an answer:

```
SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT quantity SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM table
WHERE quantity > 0
GROUP BY id, name;
```

Also, you seem to have some typos with quantity* and id* instead of article number, at least according to your table. Plus, I recommend putting both id and name in the select statement and the group by statement.